# Why is this returning a pop index out of range error?

Tags: python, oop, object

So I'm trying to simulate the NBA lottery and when I create an array of teams and attempt to assign each team its combinations within a for loop, I get a pop index out of bounds error in this line:

```
combos.append(self.combinations.pop(randint(0,len(self.combinations))))
```

However, if I simply assign one team item its combinations, no error occurs. The error occurs when I try to assign its combinations iteratively.

```
from Team import *
from LotteryMachine import *

"""Main class"""
lotteryMachine = LotteryMachine()

"""Initialize Teams"""
teams = [Team('Lakers', '81-0',1),Team('Wizards', '81-0',2)]

for team in teams:
   team.combinations=
   lotteryMachine.assignCombinations(team.numCombinations)
```

Team class:

```
 class Team():

combination_dict={1:250, 2:199, 3:156, 4:119, 5:88, 6:63, 7:43, 8:28, 9:17, 10:11, 11:8, 12:7, 13: 6, 14:5}

def __init__(self, name, record, standing):
    self.name=name
    self.record = record
    self.standing = standing
    self.numCombinations= Team.combination_dict[self.standing]

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Lottery Machine Class:

```
from random import *
class LotteryMachine():

def __init__(self):
    self.combinations = list(self.createCombinations([x for x in range(1,15)],4))
    self.deleteRandom()
    self.copyCombinations = self.combinations


def combination(self,n,k):
    return int(self.factorial(n)/(self.factorial(k)*self.factorial(n-k)))

def factorial(self,n):
    assert n>=0
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    return n*self.factorial(n-1)

def createCombinations(self,elements,length):
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        if length==1:
             yield [elements[i],]
        else:
            for next in self.createCombinations(elements[i+1:len(elements)],length-1):
                yield [elements[i],]+next

def deleteRandom(self):
    self.combinations.pop(randint(0,len(self.combinations)))

def assignCombinations(self,length):
    combos=[]
    for x in range(length):
        combos.append(self.combinations.pop(randint(0,len(self.combinations))))
    return combos
    #error occurs in above line

def drawCombinations(self):
    combos=[]
    for x in range(3):
     combos.append(self.copyCombinations.pop(randint(0, len(self.copyCombinations))))
    return combos


def __str__(self):
    return "NBA Lottery Machine"
```

Comment: Does it actually contain anything?

Comment: Yes, combinations is initialized when LotteryMachine is initialized

Answer (score 0):

The `randint` function returns a random integer from a range up to *and including* the upper bound. If you want it to generate random indexes into a list, you probably want `randrange` instead, which selects from a half-open interval (including the lower bound, but excluding the upper bound).